Why a Kubernetes persistent volume does not have namespace?
Context: 
Initially, I had a set of k8s files. Resources from the files were deployed and worked well in namespace 'namespace1'. 
Then I tried to install another copy of all k8s infrastructure to namespace 'namespace2' putting everything I had to a new Helm chart. 
The Helm chart values.yaml file set namespace of every resource to 'namespace2' because all k8s yaml files were converted by me to Helm template files and amended the way all resources to have   namespace: {{ .Values.namespace }}. 
Helm failed telling me that I already have a persistent volume in namespace "". 
Trying to understand what's wrong I looked at persistent volumes using 
kubectl get -n namespace1 pv
kubectl get -n namespace2 pv
kubectl get -n "" pv
kubectl get -n '' pv
kubectl describe -n namespace1 pv
kubectl describe -n namespace2 pv
kubectl describe -n "" pv
kubectl describe -n '' pv

and I noticed that I always see the same two my existing persistent volumes that were deployed initially to namespace 'namespace1'. 
At least I thought that I deployed them to that namespace. 
I checked the YAML file defining the persistent volumes and made sure the volumes had namespace 'namespace1' properly configured.
Then I tried
kubectl get -A pv

and got
NAMESPACE   NAME                                CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                          STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
            persistentvolume/resdb-pv-volume    100Mi      RWO            Retain           Bound    some-stuff/resdb-pv-claim    respv                   27d
            persistentvolume/sondb-pv-volume    100Mi      RWO            Retain           Bound    some-stuff/sondb-pv-claim    sonpv                   27d


Question: 
Why don't persistent volumes have a namespace displayed in the output of kubectl get? 
Nor is namespace field displayed in the output of kubectl describe. There's no Namespace: field in the output altogether. 
Don't persistent volumes in general have a namespace they belong to? 
Is it a known glitch/bug of Minikube 1.32.0 or underlying Kubernetes 1.28.3 I am using?

You shouldn't normally need to manually create PersistentVolumes, and possibly and answer to your actual problem is to remove them from your Helm chart.  When you copy the PersistentVolumeClaims into the new namespace (or better, copy a StatefulSet, and let the cluster create the PVCs) the cluster should provision new matching PersistentVolumes automatically.

@DavidMaze, I am curious if it is possible to make my non cloud installations dedicate PVs matching PVCs?
I always thought that a PV can be provisioned automatically by various cloud provisioners which is not the case in case of personal PC installations of k8s.

Minikube can dynamically create PersistentVolumes backed by local files.  Apparently Kind can as well.

Persistent volumes (PVs) in Kubernetes are cluster-wide resources, meaning they do not belong to any specific namespace. This is why when you check for PVs using kubectl, you don't see a namespace listed for them.
Unlike PVs, Persistent Volume Claims (PVCs) are tied to specific namespaces. So, while PVCs must be in a particular namespace, the PVs they claim can be accessed from any namespace across the entire cluster.
This design allows PVs to be shared and accessed by PVCs from different namespaces if necessary. The behavior you're seeing is normal and not a glitch or bug in Minikube or Kubernetes.

It is a bit strange that k8s persistent volume configuration allows to set a value to namespace field.
